# How to add an unknown amount of numbers from user input in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to add up all numbers inputted by a user, however there is no limit on how many numbers a user can input for the addition. How do I code this in linux shell script?

I have this so far:

```
firstNumber=0
secondNumber=0
number=0


echo Please enter two numbers to add up

read firstNumber
read secondNumber

echo Would you like to keep adding numbers? YES OR NO
read answer

if answer = YES
then
echo Please add another number
read number
echo $(($firstNumber +$secondNumber + $number))
fi

while answer = NO
do
echo $(($firstNumber + $secondNumber))
done
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: @Loïc I'm trying to loop through input information and store it in the sum but it's not really working

Comment: sounds like a good start, please show your code (edit your question)

Comment: You might want to rephrase the problem: sum up a list of numbers from the user, the user will flag the end of the list with empty line (or some other value). This will be easier on the user (less typing), and save you testing time

Comment: Are you trying to understand the grammar for writing loops and using `read`, or do you just want `awk '{sum += $1} END{ print sum }'`?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. What is the problem? Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @dash-o recommended, a simple entry sequence ended with ENTER is the most simple approach:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

sum=0

echo "Please enter integer numbers to add, or just RETURN to end."

while read -r number && [ -n "$number" ]; do
  if [ "$number" -eq "$number" ] 2>/dev/null; then
    sum=$((sum + number))
    echo "Sum is: $sum"
  else
    echo "$number is not a valid integer. Try again..." >&2
  fi
done
```

Or to allow multiple integers entry per line:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Save the shell's options state
shelloptions="$(set +o)"
# Disable globbing to prevent filename expansion in parameters
set -o noglob

sum=0

echo "Please enter integer numbers to add, or RETURN to end."

# Read lines until empty REPLY
while read -r && [ -n "$REPLY" ]; do

  # Split $REPLY as parameters
  # Globbing is turned-off so filenames will not mess with entries
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Explicitly intended word splitting
  set -- $REPLY

  # Iterate numbers from the parameters array
  for number in "$@"; do

    # If $number is a valid integer
    if [ "$number" -eq "$number" ] 2>/dev/null; then
      sum=$((sum + number))
    else
      echo "$number is not a valid integer." >&2
    fi
  done
  echo "Sum is: $sum"
done

# Restore the shell's options state
eval "$shelloptions"
```